# The difference between HttpCookie and Cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, httpcookie, cookiejar

So I'm confused as msdn and other tutorials tell me to use HttpCookies to add cookies via Response.Cookies.Add(cookie). But that's the problem. Response.Cookies.Add only accepts Cookies and not HttpCookies and I get this error:

cannot convert from 'System.Net.CookieContainer' to 'System.Net.Cookie'

Additionally, what's the difference between Response.Cookies.Add(cookie) and Request.CookieContainer.Add(cookie)?

Thanks for the help in advance, I'm trying to teach myself using C#.

```
// Cookie
Cookie MyCookie = new Cookie();
MyCookie.Name = "sid";
MyCookie.Value = SID;
MyCookie.HttpOnly = true;
MyCookie.Domain = ".domain.com";

// HttpCookie
HttpCookie MyCookie = new HttpCookie("sid");
MyCookie.Value = SID;
MyCookie.HttpOnly = true;
MyCookie.Domain = ".domain.com";

Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using `System.Net.HttpWebResponse`. But the above example uses `System.Web.HttpResponse` which takes `System.Web.HttpCookie` as a parameter.

**Scott Allen**

> System.Web.HttpRequest is a class used
>   on the server and inside an ASP.NET
>   application. It represents the
>   *incoming* request from a client.
>
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest is a class
>   used to make an *outgoing* request to
>   a web application.

Comment: So the next question is how does one grab the authentication cookie from the incoming request to pass to the outgoing request?