# what is the difference between System.Net.Cookie and System.Web.HttpCookie?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, client-server, webclient

I obtain a HTTPCookie, but need a Net.Cookie.  Are they just something you can recast, or how would i go about it?

Comment: Poss. duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779410/c-sharp-sharp-the-difference-between-httpcookie-and-cookie

Comment: How would i be able to convert 1 to another though?  That isnt covered, and it seems to be what I need done.

Comment: survey says:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214387/sending-cookies-using-httpcookiecollection-and-cookiecontainer  is how you go between the 2

Comment: @DavidW Definitely not a duplicate. The referenced question was never answered.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually you have two questions:

1. Difference between System.Web.HttpCookie and System.Net.Cookie
2. How to convert from HTTPCookie to a Cookie.

**Part 1)**
This question is really interesting ,I'm still thinking why there are two classes which looks pretty same ,My initial thought was `System.Web.HttpCookie inherits System.Net.Cookie` but this isn't true *both directly inherit from Object* so they are distinct classes ,but the properties matches a lot ,so this gives a hope for the solution of *part 2*.

**Part 2)**
I think its possible to convert one into another theoretically since both are just objects if you populate them the right way it will work , here a little analysis when I compared the two classes.
*Click to open in new tab to enlarge*
[image: Click to open in new tab to enlarge]

**Update:**
The System.Web is made to be used in server-based apps and System.Net can be used for client based apps.

**Some Thoughts:**

1. Write a method or a static class which can convert one object into another, I haven't check all of them but properties whose names match, there signature also matches.
2. Properties which don't exists in the another object you can stuff some  constant or a value which you know matches the scenario like `Port` number.

Good luck ,let me know how you came up with the final solution ,post the code or link.

**Some Links**
[this post has some related code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779410/c-sharp-sharp-the-difference-between-httpcookie-and-cookie)

Comment: Relevant posts on this topic https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9062e220-ebaa-4c61-a716-13fcdb2ecedb/how-to-convert-systemwebhttpcookie-to-systemnetcookie-?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Excellent answer. Also, [System.Net.Cookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.cookie) is marked as `Serializable` but [System.Web.HttpCookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcookie) is not. So `Cookie` can be serialized and deserialized for remoting across AppDomains.